# Add column to DataFrame that contains a list of column names based on a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
| A | B | C | D |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 | 7 |
```

I need to add an extra column E that contains a list of columns that fit a condition. for example >=3. So in this case it would have to look like this:

```
| A | B | C | D | E         |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 7 | [B, D]    |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 | [B, C, D] |
| 3 | 6 | 2 | 7 | [A, B, D] |
```

I've tried making a completely new dataframe with 1 column and then concatenating the two. Which didn't work.
Also tried to use `np.where`, but the DataFrame has too many columns to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution:

```
df.assign(E = df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x.ge(3)].to_list(), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D          E
0  2  4  1  7     [B, D]
1  2  5  6  7  [B, C, D]
2  3  6  2  7  [A, B, D]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with `dot`:

```
df["E"] = df.ge(3).dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",")

>>> df
   A  B  C  D      E
0  2  4  1  7    B,D
1  2  5  6  7  B,C,D
2  3  6  2  7  A,B,D
```

Edit: To get a `list`:

```
df["E"] = df.ge(3).dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",").str.split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2, 2, 3],
                   "B": [4, 5, 6],
                   "C": [1, 6, 2],
                   "D": [7]*3})

def my_func(data_, threshold=3):
    for index in data_.index:
        check = data_.loc[index].to_dict()
        data_.loc[index, "E"] = str([key for key, value in check.items() if value >= threshold])
    return data_
my_func(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reshaping with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df['E'] = (
 df.stack().ge(3).loc[lambda x: x].reset_index(level=1)
   .groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D          E
0  2  4  1  7     [B, D]
1  2  5  6  7  [B, C, D]
2  3  6  2  7  [A, B, D]
```